# Error in struct definition

Tags: g++

I have defined a structure & some functions as below in a header file

```
struct ScDetPos
{
 bool  status[MAXD];
 int   noofdetectors;
 float x[MAXD];
 float y[MAXD];
 float z[MAXD];
};


// read sc position
// this function reads sc det coordinate file and returns the structure
ScDetPos ReadScCoordinates();


// print the sccordinates
void DisplayScCoordinates(ScDetPos sc);
```

In source file I have function definition for above two functions.

```
{
 ScDetPos scpos;
 scpos = ReadScCoordinates();
 DisplayScCoordinates(scpos);
}
```

It is compiling with out any problem,

It is giving error when I use the data in the structure "ScDetPos" for some calculations and comparison as below.

```
neutron-time.cpp:240: error: ‘scpos’ was not declared in this scope
neutron-time.cpp:280: error: ‘scpos’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: can you post the complete code?

Comment: @Hari can you please post the complete code ?? With this much code it is really tough to figure out